# How to search if a collection of items are in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I am iterating through a file, and am trying to determine if a specific set of 3 items (from the file) are found together in an empty list I have made; if not, I would like to append them. If they already appear, I would like to skip over them.

However, when I run the following code:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

targets = open(file)

longest_UTR = []

counter = 0

for line in targets:

    (chromosome, locus, mir, gene, transcript, UTR_length) = line.strip("\n").split("\t")

    if [locus, mir, gene] not in longest_UTR:

        longest_UTR.append([locus, mir, gene, transcript, UTR_length])

    counter += 1

    if counter == 100:

        break

pp (longest_UTR)
```

I find that the output contains duplicates i.e. it has not skipped over the group of items even if they appear in the empty list (as shown by the arrows below).

```
['CFI', 'hsa-miR-576-5p', 'DIS3', 'ENST00000490646', '2934'],
['APOE', 'hsa-miR-642a-5p', 'WDR64', 'ENST00000425826', '2122'],
>['C2/CFB/SKIV2L', 'hsa-miR-219a-1-3p', 'GLG1', 'ENST00000422840', '4748'],
['C2/CFB/SKIV2L', 'hsa-miR-219a-1-3p', 'GLG1', 'ENST00000422840', '4748']<,
['APOE', 'hsa-miR-330-3p', 'DCAF4L1', 'ENST00000333141', '4764'],
['TMEM97/VTN', 'hsa-miR-144-3p', 'DCAF4L1', 'ENST00000333141', '4764']]
```

I would like some guidance as to why this may be the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `longest_UTR` would be a list of lists. And the if statement `if [locus, mir, gene] not in longest_UTR` would search the list `[locus, mir, gene]` in `longest_UTR`, and would never find it, as the sub-lists in `longest_UTR` are all of length 5.

Rather, you can just search for the first 3 elements of each sub-list:

```
if not any(x[:3] == [locus, mir, gene] for x in longest_UTR):
```

You should know that the order of elements would matter here. Like, if `longest_UTR` has some list with the first 3 elements as `[mir, locus, gene]`, this if statement would return `False`.

Comment: Hi, I attempted to use the any(x[:3]) method however, this returns a blank list, despite the order of elements being the same.

Comment: did you just use `any` or `not any`?

Comment: Sorry, I used any. Correcting it to 'not any' has rectified this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Lists are not hashable, therefore comparing equality between both cannot be done the way you think. list comparison can be done using [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) instead.

from pprint import pprint as pp

```
targets = open(file)

longest_UTR = []

for line in targets:
    chromosome, locus, mir, gene, transcript, UTR_length = line.strip("\n").split("\t")

    if not [set([locus, mir, gene]) < set(utr) for utr in longest_UTR]:
        longest_UTR.append([locus, mir, gene, transcript, UTR_length)])
pp (longest_UTR)
```